# Searching for empty cell of row in excel using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am attempting to have matlab tell me if a cell is either empty or has data.  The data contained in the cell will be the date if it has data.

I am currently getting the error "Undefined operator '==' for input arguments for type 'cell'".

```
x1range='b1';
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('1.xlsx',1,x1range);

if cellfun(@isnan,raw,'UniformOutput',false)==1
    fprintf('empty')
else
    fprintf('notempty')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellfun` checks whether each element `isnan` and (since you've specified non-uniform output) will return a cell array. You cannot compare a cell array using `==`. This non-uniform output is essential in your case since `isnan` on a string returns a logical *array*.

```
isnan('abcde')

% 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you actually want to check if they are empty, you likely want to use `isempty` instead of `isnan`. And you also can use uniform output (the default)

```
empty_cells = cellfun(@isempty, raw)
```

Or if you actually have `NaN` values in there, wrap `isnan` in an `any

```
empty_cells = cellfun(@(x)any(isnan(x)), raw);
```

If you want to find which cells are empty you could use `find` to get the indices

```
empty_indices = find(empty_cells);
```

Alternately, you could check if `any` or `all` of the cells are empty

```
if all(empty_cells)
    disp('All cells are empty')
elseif any(empty_cells)
    disp('Some cells are empty')
else
    disp('No cells are empty')
end
```